# How do i access the sub details in the JSON using python?

Tags: python

the python program that i am writing calls to an api that returns this json:

[Code Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0zTp.png)

How do i access the subdetails? When i run the .keys() it only lists those three top levels. I want to be able to get specific items, e.g. "Utility"

I've tried several solutions but none parse correctly. I have tried calling the list inside the dictionary, to no avail. Originally i thought it was a dictionary inside of a dictionary, but  Python thinks its a list nested into a dictionary.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It is bad to post code or data as pictures.  There is no way to copy and paste a picture into a code editor. So it will be much harder, and thus less likely, for someone to help. To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Sorry, here is a paste bin:

https://pastebin.com/BHB2bVSb

Comment: What does "I tried calling the list inside the dictionary" mean? If you show us the code you tried (and the error or wrong data you got, instead of just "to no avail"), we can probably show you how to fix it.

Comment: @JarrettDuskey, Please edit it into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

keys() function only returns the keys of dictionary, so it you call keys(), it will only return the three result. The "subdetails" you are referring to are the values of those keys. For key "SUMMARY" as an example, its value is a list instead of dict (note the "[" after the key). However, the list only has a single element. This is quite common in json. To retrive "Utility", all you need to do is     data['SUMMARY'][0]['Utility']

Maybe to help you understand the data structure better, call the "values()" and "items()" function to see what it returns.

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a dict of lists of dicts, simply use an index of `0` to access the first item of the list if there is always only one item in each list. For example, if your JSON object is stored as variable `data`, then the value of `Utility` can be accessed with `data['SUMMARY'][0]['Utility']`.